# Настройки Laravel 5.4 для сервера без права записи

Tags: laravel, сессия, кэширование, views

Как отключить в Laravel 5.4 создание и запись всех файлов?
Список директорий (вроде полный):

- myapp\bootstrap\cache\
- myapp\storage\logs\
- myapp\storage\framework\cache\
- myapp\storage\framework\sessions\
- myapp\storage\framework\views\

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, что [никак](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration):

> Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

Встречный вопрос - это что еще за сервер такой без права записи? Как туда таким образом попало приложение?